# Triangular network topology: Incorrect entry in routing table. (Persistent between reboots.) (Debian 10 & Raspberry Pi)

Tags: debian, networking, routing, router

My Debian 10 workstation has 2 network interfaces. This is my routing table (simplified)

```
ip route
default via 192.168.2.254 dev enx0050b668976b proto dhcp metric 100 
10.0.0.0/8 dev enp6s0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.1 
10.0.0.2 dev enx0050b668976b proto static scope link metric 101 
192.168.2.0/24 dev enx0050b668976b proto kernel scope link src 192.168.2.10 metric 100 
192.168.122.0/24 via 10.0.0.2 dev enx0050b668976b proto static metric 101
```

It doesn't make any sense what so ever. Specifically, lines 3 and 5 are nonsensical.

```
10.0.0.2 dev enx0050b668976b proto static scope link metric 101 
192.168.122.0/24 via 10.0.0.2 dev enx0050b668976b proto static metric 101
```

The IP address `10.0.0.2` is for interface `enp6s0` not `enx0050b668976b`, which has the IP address `192.168.2.10`.

Due to the fact that it is nonsensical, my network shares are broken.

This appears to be consistent between reboots.

What are the possible ways that a routing table can be populated?

- Configuration files?
- DHCP server or info from other systems on the network?

I don't know why my routing table contains this information. My question is in two parts:

- How is the routing table populated between reboots? (How do I stop the wrong lines appearing on next boot?)
- How do I fix it? (How do I put the right lines in for the next boot?)

## Linked question - this is super weird

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/113637/erroneous-entry-in-routing-table

I tracked down the source of the problem to an entry on a Raspberry Pi which acts as a router on my network. I have not yet solved this issue.

This question was closed by some moderator who commented that more information was needed, before immediately closing the question without waiting for that information to be added... So I've migrated that information back over here.

## Summary of Raspberry Pi side issues:

There is an erroneous entry in my Raspberry Pi 4's routing table. This device functions as the router for my local network. There is a line with an IP address related to a virtual machine which runs on a server I have attached to my local network.

I shutdown all the systems on my network, disconnected all network cables, and rebooted my Raspberry Pi.

However, after rebooting the erroneous entry is still there. <s>I have no idea how it got there. It may have been picked up automatically via network activity, or I might have put it in there accidentally by typing a command into the wrong terminal, thus sending it to the wrong machine. (I cannot recall.)</s>

<s>I assume there must be a config file on my Pi which has an entry for this IP... Where might this file be?</s>

(See below, found source of this)

<s>The Pi runs dnsmasq and has a wireless AP running. That's about it.</s>

<s>When I type `ip route` after reboot the routing table is as expected.</s>

<s>When I press the power button on my workstation, before the BIOS post beep has even happened, `ip route` displays a routing table with a new, erroneous entry.</s>

<s>If I then unplug the ethernet cable of my workstation, the erroneous entry goes away. Plug back in, it comes back.</s>

<s>This is before the workstation OS has booted, so it can't be an config problem with my workstation. It must be somewhere on the Pi.</s>

## Source of problem found but no solution (yet)

I did a grep search for the network address which is causing the problem. It turns out this is inside the config file

```
/lib/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-hooks/40-route

ip route add 192.168.122.0/24 via 192.168.2.12
```

This makes perfect sense for most devices on the network. This is a static route to the server (virtual machine) `192.168.122.166/24` which is resident on the server (physical machine) with ip `192.168.2.12/24`.

The problem is that my workstation has a direct static link to this server.

Here is a network topology diagram.

```
workstation <---- direct link ----> server [contains VM]
         ^                               ^
         |                               |
         V                               |
        router [r-pi] <------------------+
```

The configuration my workstation picks up at boot time appears to be coming from this Raspberry Pi (router). This configuration would likely be correct for all other devices on this net, but it is not correct for my workstation due to the static link in place between it and the server.

Any ideas about how to correct this?

This is the routing table on my pi: (relevant lines only, these are all ok)

```
192.168.122.0/24 via 192.168.2.12 dev eth0
```

This is the routing table on my workstation: (relevant lines only)

```
10.0.0.0/8 dev enp6s0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.1 linkdown [correct, link is down, interface name correct]
10.0.0.2 dev enx0050.... proto static scope link metric 101 [incorect interface name, should be enp6s0]
192.168.2.0/24 dev enx0050.... proto kernel scope link src 192.168.2.100 metric 100 [correct]
192.168.122.0/24 via 10.0.0.2 dev enx0050... proto static metric 101 [incorrect, interface name wrong]
```

Comment: As 192.168.122.0/24 is the default for libvirt (handling VM hypervisor QEMU/KVM), you should check if you're using this tool and if so what you configured there.

Comment: @A.B I have libvirt on both machines actually - could you tell me where I might be able to find any relevant config files and whether this is possibly due to a configuration error on the server rather than the workstation?

Comment: General hint: Questions are reopened if the required information is added.

Comment: @HaukeLaging Without going into detail, the question was re-opened. Then closed again. Both times for not legitimate (not following policy) reasons